# Invalid public key due to ingestion error: Invalid Content

Tags: amp-html

I'm tryining to invalidate some AMP pages. I read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-cache) and some GitHub issues and the more I know the less I understand. ;)

I guess my public key was never crawled.

Via
https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-cache#update-rsa-keys

> If you want to update your RSA key, you can access the RSA key through the AMP Cache link and Google may crawl your new RSA key
>   within several hours. Here is the AMP Cache link:
>
> https://example-com.< cache.updateCacheApiDomainSuffix >/r/s/example.com/.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub

So according to this my URL is:
https://www-bronchicum-de.cdn.ampproject.org/r/s/www.bronchicum.de/.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub
The key is located at: https://www.bronchicum.de/.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub (served publicly via plain/text)

Unfortunately I only get:

> 404. That’s an error.
>
> The requested URL /r/s/www.bronchicum.de/.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

When I'm trying to invalidate the cache (using [digitalbrands/amp-cache](https://github.com/DigitalBrands/amp-cache)) or a self written bash script, I get the following:

> 403. That’s an error.
>
> Your client does not have permission to get URL
>   /update-cache/c/s/www.bronchicum.de/amp?amp_action=flush&amp_ts=1572261663&amp_url_signature=BxYM4-ky5wEVmeixpTqMZec3aDhUxcbkT32-kSXufPeO1fGFJ_p7I-xiPKih0oF5AOJy3XnLIvXy_btLXblOALb82BKvHj4UWtiWmtSgV3n-vH5_TVlrDU88UAa_EEZ4sDODwt2Auo1gREd4tZ_BDdXSbDBU5muCbld8KGiSO7mbQ62wWjWhZeXyo6AXqg7AmgCp5wdlwT1f00miYvALUB0gk7f9uDjTsEGIpEvGEwWQE0MllSiYXZ0XnwW2oGaJh8e3ofx0vx72omy9g5i6szgEgT_QR8hEPV_FTXN6V9n0E9A3drAOdyXGVKmFQHLP-knAI-sqfcrRMH2pNc856A
>   from this server. (Client IP address: x.x.x.x)
>
> Invalid public key due to ingestion error: Invalid Content That’s all we know.

Soooo... something wrong with my public key?

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -signature signature.bin -verify pulic-key.pem url.txt
```

Says "Verified OK". Can anyone please help me? :)

Comment: I am somewhat facing the same / similar issue - have you been able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that your response for `/.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub` has `Context-Type` header with value `text/plain`.

For example, if you have an apache httpd server, then add the following lines in the `.htaccess` file.

```
<FilesMatch "apikey.pub">
ForceType text/plain
</FilesMatch>
```

After this, try submitting `update cache` and it should say 'OK'.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work for me - I've still got the "ingestion error"

Comment: what is your site URL?

Comment: https://bachtrack.com Thanks for asking, but I've now got it working, by nothing more than starting again with a new set of keys. I wish I understood why...